# remove leading whitespace from a used bash parameter in output

Tags: bash

I am getting the following result:

```
alias foo="echo hello`$1`"
foo bar         #outputs `hello bar` with an unwanted space
```

the desired output is `hellobar`

--- Edit: ---

I have found a workaround for the above for now:

```
foo(){ echo hello$1 }
foo bar      #outputs hellobar
```

Comment: Or better use `printf 'hello%s\n' "$1"`

Comment: Your report is not accurate; it should print `something: command not found` on standard error, where `something` is the _current_ value of `$1` in your interactive shell. If `$1` is unset, it will work without an error, but define an alias whose value is `echo hello`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is as expected. Alias does not use arguments.

So, what happens is:

```
alias foo="echo hello`$1`"
```

This defines `foo` as an alias of

```
echo hello`$1`
```

`$1` of your current shell is probably empty. The backticks around it will execute `$1` as command at the time you define the alias and use the output. And executing nothing will result in nothing. So the alias effectively becomes `echo hello`.

Then you do:

```
test bar
```

Replacing `test` with `foo` (it is probably what you actually did), results therefore in

```
echo hello bar
```

and that is where your space comes from.

If you want to create an alias-like thing that accepts arguments, look at functions.

```
foo2(){
    echo "Hello$1"
}

foo2 bar
```

which is what you wanted.

Comment: Actually, `foo` is simply `echo hello`, and `$1` gets evaluated as a command. If it is unset, nothing happens. If it is a random string, you get an error message. If it is a random string which happens to also be a valid command, you get the output of that command after `hello` in the alias, without a space. The lack of quoting in the alias definition might complicate matters further.

Comment: That is what "executing nothing will result in nothing" was ment to mean. I'l elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: The crucial correction is that this happens when the alias is defined, not when it is used.